# how can we select specific rows from a .csv file using d3js

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

**input file**

```
perf_month,Jan-15,Feb-15,Mar-15,Apr-15,May-15,Jun-15,Jul-15,Aug-15,Sep-15,Oct-15,Nov-15,Dec-15,Jan-16,Feb-16,Mar-16<br>
open_acc,5843,7126,7682,5517,6965,7519,2579,2572,8108,356,8950,718,1214,6523,8068<br>
inter_sales,6086,6910,3094,1027,7797,8109,6510,8451,311,5682,9716,8561,8044,7141,8790<br>
exter_sales,6345,3933,9529,1457,7920,8608,3910,971,6070,5859,7899,5342,3466,2005,4357<br>
close_acc,6594,1712,1358,1830,3437,7454,3697,6621,9882,1308,3069,3576,9583,5780,6455<br>
balance,4128,1490,8354,3470,7506,9309,7637,9082,4029,1256,9010,6117,1162,8028,1078<br>
payment,1179,8452,8040,2082,8351,1494,1877,2772,5985,477,7153,1857,1572,5698,1436<br>
```

**output form**

```
perf_month,Jan-15,Feb-15,Mar-15,Apr-15,May-15,Jun-15,Jul-15,Aug-15,Sep-15,Oct-15,Nov-15,Dec-15,Jan-16,Feb-16,Mar-16
open_acc,5843,7126,7682,5517,6965,7519,2579,2572,8108,356,8950,718,1214,6523,8068<br>
exter_sales,6345,3933,9529,1457,7920,8608,3910,971,6070,5859,7899,5342,3466,2005,4357<br>
payment,1179,8452,8040,2082,8351,1494,1877,2772,5985,477,7153,1857,1572,5698,1436<br>
```

**and after that i want to create table from these rows using d3js**

Answer (score -2):

To use the data just use `d3.csv`.

For example :

```
d3.csv("csvPath.csv",function(data){
//use the data variable above as you csv for example

data.forEach(function(d){
console.log(d)// this will log each line of data, so the first one would be
//d.perf_month = "open_acc" and so on
})

})
```

As for using this to populate a table there are many examples :

- https://bl.ocks.org/ndarville/7075823
- http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/473f0cf66196a008cf99